# which is better here to use a ASIQueue or two different instances of ASIHTTPRequest

Tags: ios, ios4, ios5

In my view controller I have two `UIScrollViews`. One is to display latest news updates from server and other is to display some images from the server. So I have to parse two json feeds for these data. I am using `ASIHTTPRequest` for the network services.

So in my `-viewWillAppear:` method I'm calling two separate asynchronous instances of `ASIHTTPRequest`

```
-(void)viewWillAppear{

    call news JSON and parse
    call image JSOn and parse

    process news Data and display the data in UI
    process image Data and display
}
```

So which is better here to use a `ASIQueue` or two different instances of `ASIHTTPRequest`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems all programmatic from your pseudocode for `viewWillAppear:`. So I'd say use an `ASINetworkQueue` and set the completion handlers of the requests to a function which will action the appropriate display calls:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear
{
    // init news ASIHTTPRequest (set completion handler to newsDownloaded:)
    // init image ASIHTTPRequest (set completion handler to imagesDownloaded:)
    // add both of the requests to [ASINetworkQueue sharedQueue]
}

- (void)newsDownloaded:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // parse news JSON
    // process news Data and display the data in UI
}

- (void)imagesDownloaded:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
{
    // parse image JSON
    // process image Data and display
}
```

Or, instead of using methods, you can write the parse and processing code in a code block and set `completionBlock` on the ASIHTTPRequests.

Comment: thanks darvidsOn.. So to parse the downloaded data in a seperate thread i can use GCD queues in the finished methods ... right ?

Comment: If you want, sure! :) It runs by default on a background thread, so I think if you use the `completionBlock` methods those code blocks will execute in the background. You can definitely also dispatch additional worker threads from those finished methods, there's no restriction on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to track the progress of each request individually,  I recommend `ASINetworkQueue` instead of two `ASIHTTPRequest`s.

Comment: Strange, my advice would have been the exact opposite. To have a better view of each request's individual progress, use 2 separate requests.